# PHP: How to return a multidimentional array from a function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, return-value

My code is similar to;

```
function myFunc() {
    $myArry = array();
    $myArry[1]['first'] = "First";
    $myArry[1]['second'] = "Second";
    $myArry[2]['first'] = "First";
    $myArry[2]['second'] = "Second";
    $myArry[3]['first'] = "First";
    $myArry[3]['second'] = "Second";
    echo "before return: ".count($myArry);
    return $myArry;
}

// main code
$returnedArry = array(myFunc());
echo "after return: ".count($returnedArry);
```

Output:

```
before return: 3
after return: 1
```

What is happening here, can someone please explain? Also, what should I be doing?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, please ignore this post, I have asked a Mod to close it, I have a typo in my code so this question is completely invalid

Answer (score 8):

```
$returnedArry = array(myFunc());
```

That line of code is putting your array into another array. Since it is the only element in that array the count is 1. What you really want is this:

```
$returnedArry = myFunc();
```

Comment: @javano then you did something *else* wrong. This is the proper way to return the array.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that explains why that didn't work. Although I was actually referencing a different function in my code, so this question is completely moot. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 1):

You're wrapping the returned `$myArry` in a new array, and thus it is the single entry in `$returnedArry`.

```
    $returnedArray = array(
           array(
              0 => array(
                      'first' => "First",
                      'second' => "Second"
                   ),
              1 => ...
              2 => ...
          )
    )
```

To produce the results you're looking for:

```
    $returnedArray = myFunc();
```

In the future, you can use `print_r` or `var_dump` to help show you whats in these arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the input, that explains why that didn't work. Although I was actually referencing a different function in my code, so this question is completely moot. Sorry for the inconvenience!